# Navbar Horizontal list problems, not centering or taking up full width

Tags: list, width, nav

I've been frustrated by this problem for days on end and just cannot solve it. My CSS/HTML skills are somewhat elementary, any help much appreciated.

(To start let me mention that I am using Weebly editor and using the HTML/CSS editor to customize.)

So I have a horizontal list which is inside a wrapper. The problem is I cannot get it to take up the entire width of the `#navwrap ul {`  or the `#navwrap parent/s`. Also I can't get the list to center inside its parent.

I have put borders around the elements to see what is going on. (Hopefully I can attach a pic). Some of the CSS is leftover from trying so many different things to fix this, so some if it may be unnecessary.

HTML:

```
    <div id="header-wrap">
        <table id="header">
            <tr id="header-row">
                <td id="logowrap"><img  id="logo" src="img.svg"></td>                       
                    <td id="navwrap">{menu}
                    </td>
                        ETC...
CSS:

    #navwrap {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: none;
}

#navwrap ul {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid orange;

}


#navwrap li {
    height:40px;
    float:auto;
    display:inline-table;
    border:1px solid green;

}

#navwrap a {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color:white;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I managed to fix this with a display: table (wrapper) display:table-row (ul) display:table-cell solution.